# Deployment .ear file to Glassfish 3.1.2

Tags: java, glassfish, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I built ADF application using Jdeveloper 12.1.3 and tried to deploy the .ear file to Glassfish 3.1.2, but during the deployment I got this error message as follows, my JDK version is 1.7

```
Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:  org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

in the server log:

```
2016-09-17T07:33:26.509+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config|_ThreadID=84;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory' was not configured properly.
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/adf/share/logging/ADFLogger : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

---

Any help to fix this Please
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/adf/share/logging/ADFLogger : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Try using another version of ADFLogger.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's all about your's JDK version. You said that your glassfish server uses JDK version 1.7. Make sure that this version is greater than 52 build.